# Butter separation in english toffee candy

Tags: baking, butter, candy

I've read recently some articles about English toffee candy and the issue of butter separation was mentioned there.

I am looking for further information abut this phenomenon (what causes this separation of butter from the candy during cooking) and how can one prevent the separation
besides using an emulsifier (like lecithin).

Someone has mentioned that salt has a stabilizing effect on the emulsion, is it true?

Comment: Can you link one or more of these articles?   Was this in home scale toffee baking, or commercial scale toffee?  And what style of toffee, hard or soft?

Comment: See also, at least for preventive advise:  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9371/what-is-causing-my-butter-toffee-to-separate

Comment: I don't see why this has close votes. If you disbelieve that it happens, it has happened to me too, trying to stir the butter into the sugar syrup and not succeeding, ending up with caramel swimming in molten butter.

Answer (score 4):

Butter separation doesn't only refer to the butter separating from the toffee (sugar), butter is make of milk fat rendered and the milk solids, when butter separates this is due to these parts separating. This is the fat that you see on the toffee, this usually comes from the components cooling at different speeds.

As with anything that you are making using melted butter, like a hollandaise sauce, adding a spoon or two of **very hot water** and agitating helps with the dispersion of both the fats and the heat. Stirring is an important component to ensure the heat is equally distributed throughout the mixture.

Thanks to @Aaronut for correcting the language!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the fat separating from everything else is pretty much the problem. The milk solids are a pretty minor component.

Comment: Why the down vote? This answers the question...

Comment: @Jefromi perhaps I should clarify the answer with: butter is made of 2 parts, the fat (oil) you see is one of the parts of the butter. When it separates this means the sugar and milk solids mixed, and the oil in the butter didn't.

Comment: What is more likely to separate from the butter emulsion is the approximately 18% water phase, not the milk solids which are mostly either casein, or sugars (dissolved in the water).   The downvote is probably because the science is questionable.  For example, water is *not* an emulsifier.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ although the science might seem questionable to you, for almost everything where you are mixing oil and water: mayonnaise, hollandaise, toffee, fudge, and more adding water - very cold for some or very hot for others - and whisking works as a stabilizer to bring the components back together.

Comment: As for **what** separates: butter is an emulsion. The milk solids in this emulsion easily bind to the sugars and water in the mixture where the oil does not, when the oil separates from the mixture it is usually due to the butter not remaining emulsified. Usually  this is because the solids (milk/sugar/etc.) are cooling faster and clumping together while the oil remains liquid so the emulsion can't hold.

Comment: Like I said, the separation is fat from everything else, and the everything else does include the milk solids, but it's almost entirely sugar. As for the emulsification... when you start cooling the toffee (the point at which it's prone to separation), *there is no water in it*. You've boiled it all off, and are cooking it at a temperature well over the boiling point of water. There's no way water is going to help you.

Comment: @Jefromi perhaps you should write an answer, you seem to know more than I do and I could benefit from you experience.

Comment: @DaniëlW.Crompton Unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience here; I don't know whether salt helps or how to easily fix it without an actual emulsifier, as the question says.

Comment: I do have quite a bit of experience making toffee and fudge, but apparently I'm not able to put it down in a manner that will be accepted.

Comment: I think the problem is your classification of water as "acting as an emulsifier". What you probably meant to say was just that adding water and agitating helps with the dispersion of both the fats and the heat. You're just trying to get everything to a more-or-less uniform consistency and the water facilitates stirring. It doesn't emulsify and you don't need an emulsifier, that's what the butter's already doing.

Answer (score 0):

Pertaining to salt acting as a "stabilizer", I have this experience to offer - I never had a significant issue dissolving the sugar into the butter (first step), until I switched from salted butter to unsalted - suddenly I had water that could not be eliminated.  Some advise that adding 1/8 to 1/4 tsp salt per 4oz will rectify this, but I found this not to be true in two attempts.  When I switched back to salted butter, this frustrating problem went away.